# Как лучше пройтись по таблице и отметить нужные колонки по заданному условию?

Tags: html, jquery, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это табличка, крестики и галочки это строка, ниже строка но уже со своей таблицей (раскрывается как спойлер). 
Задача состоит в том, чтобы отмечать галочкой или крестиком те колонки в которых есть хотя бы одна точка.
Если есть - ставим галочку, если пусто - крестик. Именно по вертикали.

Как такое сделать? Пробовал через each и поиском по индексу, но чет фигня какая то получается.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, [таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/ffpc68ao/1/):

```
$('#main > tbody > tr:even').each(function (i, line) {
    var tds = $('td',line),
        indx = checkVals(line, tds.length);
    tds.each(function (i, td) {
        $(td).text(indx.indexOf(i) < 0 ? 'X' : 'V');
    });

});

function checkVals(line, cnt) {
    return $('tr td', $(line).next('tr')).map(function (i, td) {
        return $.trim($(td).text()) !== '' ? i % cnt : null;
    }).get();
}
```

**UPD** К комментарию ниже:

```
$('.option_item .option_short').each(function (i, line) {
    var tds = $('li:not(:first)', line),
        indx = checkVals(line, tds.length);
    tds.each(function (i, td) {
        $(td).text(indx.indexOf(i) < 0 ? 'X' : 'V');
    });
});

function checkVals(line, cnt) {
    return $('ul li:not(:first-child)', $(line).next('.option_detail')).map(function (i, td) {
        return $.trim($(td).text()) !== '' ? i % cnt : null;
    }).get();
}
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы помочь подправить данный код под другую разметку? [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/pjde9uhz/) С первой частью я вроде как разобрался, а с функцией не получается, везде "X" выводит. Буду рад помощи.

Comment: @Didorri,  дополнил в ответе